# How can I access the object on which a category method was called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I'm using `@implementation` to add a new function to `UIView`.

```
@implementation UIView (test)
    - (void)newFunction {

    }
@end
```

Now, in the `newFunction` I want to "grab" the object (`UIView`) that was used when calling the function.

For example when I call `newFunction` within `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [myView newFunction];
}
```

I want the `newFunction` to know what object was used to make the call (in this case, `myView`).

A simple solution would be to pass it along when making the call (`[myView newFunction:myView]`), but that is **not** what I am looking for.

I looked at [Apple's documentation on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1), but didn't really find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is called a category (not @implementation). It is an extension to the `UIView` class (in this case).

Generalcally:

```
@implementation __CLASS_TO_EXTEND__ (__CATEGORY_NAME__)
```

The category, as it is an extension, *is* the instance that you call the method on. So, you use `self` as you usually would to access the current instance.

Comment: I experienced a crash when using `self` the first time, but after using the Xcode's `Clean` function to clean the project, it worked. Thanks for you answer tho.

Answer (score 2):

```
#import "UIView+UIView_Category.h"

@implementation UIView (UIView_Category)
- (void)newFunction
{
    NSLog(@"Object = %@",self);
}
@end
```